# Ruby testing on stable debian server

Tags: debian, package-management, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a dedicated debian 5.0 server, which runs the "stable" tree.

Now I want to install [testing] ruby 1.8.7 - but my system isnt configured for installing testing packages via apt-get.

How can I do that? I only want ruby to be testing - all other packages should be upgraded with the "stable" tree.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512906/debian-how-can-i-pull-a-single-package-with-dependencies-from-another-repository/513078#513078

The mechanics are exactly the same despite that having been written for etch using packages from lenny. As a further suggestion, always use the name of the distribution rather than 'stable' as to avoid being bitten by an unplanned upgrade around release time. Feel free to use 'testing' though.

Answer (score 0):

[Michael Greenly](http://blog.michaelgreenly.com/2008/08/multiple-versions-of-ruby-on-ubuntu-2.html) has a nice description of how to do it on Ubuntu. My guess is that it will not need much tweaking to work on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitly check out [Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/). It is often faster and needs less memory than the variant of your distribution. It is also very easy to install.

Comment: FYI: REE (and Ruby 1.8) is deprecated as of 2012