# Installing latest stable ruby (1.9.2 p290) with apt-get

Tags: debian, apt, ruby

This is on a debian server.  But is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Depends which version of Debian that you're on.

Debian squeeze, the current stable version, has a [package for 1.9.2](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ruby1.9.1).  Sid, the unstable version, has the version you're looking for, [1.9.2 p290](http://packages.debian.org/sid/ruby1.9.1); but whether the unstable branch is right for what you're doing is up to you.

Comment: When I install apt-get install ruby1.9.1 it installs ruby 1.9.1p378.  And apt-get install1.9.2 doesn't exist..  I'm confused.

Comment: Already answered two years ago: http://serverfault.com/questions/47056/ruby-testing-on-stable-debian-server

Comment: @Jeremy Have you run `apt-get update`?